# javascript error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&"

Tags: javascript

I was trying to do something like this in console

```
var a = {title : '123'}
a && a.title //" 123"
```

but when I do this I have an error

```
{title : '123'} && '123'
**ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token &&**
```

I don't understand what conversions V8 did

Answer (score 5):

The first part is parsed as a block with a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). So what follows is the start of a statement. `&&` is a binary operator (meaning taking two operands), it can't start a statement.

Make the first part an expression by using parenthesis :

```
({title : '123'}) && '123'
```

Comment: javascript's creative parsing never ceases to suprise me.

Comment: @cobbal It's not "creative" at all and is very well-defined in the ECMAScript specification. JavaScript, like other C-dialect languages has a difference between Statements and Expressions. This particular error message is the result of such grammar construct division.

Comment: @user2864740 the creative part would be "all expressions are also statements, well, unless they start with a curly brace, then they can't be because we have to disambiguate somehow", and probably several other related edge cases.